# Как правильно сделать валидацию в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, валидация

Лирическое отступление: Недавно начал изучать laravel для проекта, естественно учился по гайдам из ютуба поглядывая в документацию. Начал делать с админ панели по гайду одного чувака, он говорил про валидацию, но он сказал что это легко сделать и опустил эту тему. В итоге я сам пришел к валидации и зашел в тупик

Собственно мой **вопрос**:
есть такой код в resource controller

```
 /**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Models\Tarif  $tarif
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, Tarif $tarif)
{
    $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required|unique:tarif|max:35',
        'price' => 'required|numeric',
        'speed' => 'required|numeric',
        'enabled' => 'required|boolean',
        'description' => 'nullable|string',
    );
    $validated = $request->validate($rules);

    // $tarif->name = $request->name;
    // $tarif->price = $request->price;
    // $tarif->speed = $request->speed;
    // $tarif->enabled = $request->enabled;
    // $tarif->description = $request->description;
    // $tarif->save();

    // return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Обновлено');
    
}
```

по гайдам, по идее, должна работать валидация, но выходит исключение

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view
> not found: 1146 Table 'core.tarif' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*)
> as aggregate from `tarif` where `name` = Школьник)

такая таблица у меня есть, но с окончанием, tarifs.

И ругается именно на `$validated = $request->validate($rules);`

Без самой валидации, все отлично работает.

Я смотрел примеры валидации, но не нашел примера, где бы выглядел update и store как в моем проекте.

Прошу помощи, что же я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно дело в том, что в 'name' у вас прописана таблица unique:tarif, а не unique:tarifs

Comment: Да, спасибо! Сам бы я топтался полдня на месте.